# dial tcp: lookup dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local on 100.100.2.138:53: no such host

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am using the traefik as the kubernets edge node gateway, today when I upgrade the centos linux kernel from 3.10 to 5.4, I found the traefik 2.10.5 forward rest api always return null. this is the middleware defined:

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  labels:
    k8slens-edit-resource-version: v1alpha1
  name: jwt-token-auth
  namespace: reddwarf-pro
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: >-
      http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify
    trustForwardHeader: true
```

And I found error log from traefik debug info:

```
time="2023-11-13T15:49:17Z" level=debug msg="Error calling http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify. Cause: Get \"http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify\": dial tcp: lookup dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local on 100.100.2.138:53: no such host" middlewareName=reddwarf-pro-jwt-token-auth@kubernetescrd middlewareType=ForwardedAuthType
```

what should I do to fix it? I can access the url `http://dolphin-post-service.reddwarf-pro.svc.cluster.local:11014/post/auth/access_token/verify` from other pod but not traefik pod.